# Cant open the server correctly

Tags: python, django

Can you please help me, I have downloaded the project social. Then, I went to that folder using the command line, and typed migrate then runserver, I get these warning in my command line:

```
C:\django\social\social\urls.py:25: RemovedInDjango110Warning: 
django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 
1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() 
instances instead.
url(r'^checkuser/$', views.checkuser, name='checkuser'),

C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py:37:    
RemovedInDjango110Warning: You haven't defined a TEMPLATES setting. You must 
do so before upgrading to Django 1.10. Otherwise Django will be unable to 
load templates.
"unable to load templates.", RemovedInDjango110Warning)

C:\django\social\mysite\urls.py:6: RemovedInDjango110Warning:
django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django   
1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url()   
instances instead.
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

AFter I try to go to that server, I get 404 message. Here is the script for social/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from social import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# main page
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
# signup page
url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
# register new user
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
# login page
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
# logout page
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
# members page
url(r'^members/$', views.members, name='members'),
# friends page
url(r'^friends/$', views.friends, name='friends'),
# user profile edit page
url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
# messages page
url(r'^messages/$', views.messages, name='messages'),
# Ajax: check if user exists
url(r'^checkuser/$', views.checkuser, name='checkuser'),
)
```

Comment: What "project social"? Do you have a URL?

Comment: Can you copy and paste your traceback?  Do you have Debug on?

Comment: Here is the url
https://github.com/abylikhsanov/social

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
)
```

to

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

to get rid of the urlpatterns warnings. `urlpatterns` have to be a list in newer Django versions. You can also remove the `patterns` import.

And add this to your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```